# The command 'random.choice(list)' doesn't give any output

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, discord, discord.py

I had been working on making a discord bot using python.

I put a `random.choice` to get a message from the list **flirt**. Furthermore, the function is required to read for specific words from the list **sad** and then respond to **flirt**.

Here's my code of python:

```
async def on_message(message):

    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    for word in sad:
        if word in message.content:
            response = random.choice(flirt)
            await message.reply(response)
            break
```

Both lists example:

```py
sad = ["sad", "depressed", "lonely", "miserable"]
```

```py
flirt = ["Baby I will be the broom that sweeps all the sadness in your heart.", "If a star would cure sadness, your heart would be empty of sadness."]
```

Comment: Strange. 1/ what do you mean by `random.choice` is not working? Does the script hang? Does the function return nothing? or a empty string? etc.  2/ Are you sure `random.choice` is called ? that `flirt` in the call is the the one that you defined? etc. you can test by defining your own `random_choice` function and log in it the parameter and the value returned by `random.choice`

Comment: Hey, 
1. script doesn't hang
2. function returns nothing
3. random.choice was called and library was imported too
Still nothing happens

Answer (score 1):

Do you have `@client.event` before `on_message()`?

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
...
```

It's the only thing I changed and your code works flawlessly.

You might also want to add [`lower()`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/lower) to catch words that are not in lowercase (ex. SAD):

```py
for word in sad:
    if word in message.content.lower():
```

Comment: I had used ```@client.event``` before this and rn i am the one giving input to the bot just to check, so everything is manually lowercased.

Comment: Then it should work fine. Do you get any errors or you don't get any output at all?

Comment: No errors, I don't get any output at all too. i don't know what's the problem here

Comment: Maybe check if your `on_message` works at all with `print("test")` for example.

Comment: Okay, i'll try.

Comment: ```on_message``` does gives out print

Comment: Then maybe try to enable [intents.messages](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_message#discord.Intents.messages).

Comment: It is also enabled